# how to store document in filnet in specific path based on properties?

Tags: esb, ibm-integration-bus, filenet-p8

is it doable to save a document  in specific folder in filenet without providing the path or folder id from the client application by configuring the document class to be saved in the specific path based on properties or metadata ?

Comment: Please take more time over your question. Explain what you are doing, what went wrong, what you have tried, and why your fixes did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want documents to be automatically saved in a folder, but the specific folder depends on what properties the created document has. If that's the case, I suggest you use an `EventActionHandler` and an asynchronous Subscription that listens to the document's Creation Event. It requires a bit of coding, but a few lines of code should be enough.

Check out the API documentation here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNW2F_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.java.doc/com/filenet/api/engine/EventActionHandler.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you create your java class and add it as a code module, you can create an Event Action to invoke that action on document check-in. You probably want to invoke it on any check-in so if they change the controlling property, it will change the filed folder(s).